# How can I generate first n elements of the sequence 3^i * 5^j * 7^k?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, number-theory, enumeration

How can I efficiently generate the first N elements of the sequence $3^i 5^j 7^k$, where $i,j,k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I've googled around a bit and [found the sequence in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A147576), but I don't really see a simple way of generating it.

Comment: These are called "Hamming numbers" (or "regular numbers" by non-computer scientists). Look that up, and you'll find lots and lots of hits.

Comment: I disagree with closing as "not computer science": the request is for an efficient algorithm to perform a particular task.

Answer (score 15):

Here I assume $0\in \mathbb N$. If you disagree start with $105$.

Let $S$ be the sequence of numbers of the form $3^i5^j7^k$. Our task is to generate these numbers in order.
Apart from $1$ each number added is of the form $3\cdot x$, $5\cdot y$ or $7\cdot z$ where $x,y,z$ are previous numbers in the sequence. We can generate $S$ by shifting $x,y,z$ along the sequence.

So, first put $1$ into $S$, and set $x,y,z$ equal to $1$.

Now repeat: Take the minimum value $m$ of $3\cdot x$, $5\cdot y$ and $7\cdot z$, and add $m$ to the sequence $S$. The $x,y,z$ for which the minimum was taken are shifted to the next element of $S$. This might be more than one, or even all three.

$\newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}$
$\begin{array}{r|rr|rr|rr} S & x & {}*3 & y & {}*5 & z & {}*7 & \\\hline
1 & 1 & \ul{3} & 1 & 5 & 1 & 7 \\
3 & 3 & 9 &   & \ul{5} &   & 7 \\
5 &   & 9 & 3 & 15 &   & \ul{7} \\
7 &   & \ul{9} &   & 15 & 3 & 21 \\
9 & 5 & \ul{15} &   & \ul{15} &  & 21 \\
15 & 7 & \ul{21} & 5 & 25 &   & \ul{21} \\
21 & 9 & 27 &   & \ul{25} & 5 & 35 \\
25 &   & \ul{27} & 7 & 35 &   & 35 \\
27 & 15 & 45 &   & \ul{35} &   & \ul{35} \\
35 &    & \ul{45} & 9 & \ul{45} & 7 & 49 \\
45 & 21 & 63 & 15 & 75 &   & 49 
\end{array}$

Works in linear time, as we need to take the minimum of three numbers in each step.

Comment: Great answer, but took me a while understand that table. If anyone finds this a bit hard to understand, I've added code at https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/131704/9173, which is hopefully helpful.

Comment: May need a bit of clarification regarding run time: the input is m which has lg m bits. So if the run time was O(m) this would be considered exponential time.

Comment: @Kaveh Yes, this is certainly not Turing machine complexity, but rather "number of steps" complexity.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a weighted, directed graph, with a vertex $v_i$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$. There is an edge with weight $j-i$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$ if $j\in\{3i,5i,7i\}$.

Now run Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. It will expand exactly the nodes from your sequence and do so in order. This gives an $n\log n$ algorithm to enumerate the first $n$ elements, since the graph has maximum out-degree $3$.

Comment: Given $N$, what is the exact (finite?) graph you create? How many nodes do you need to cover the first $N$ sequence elements?

Comment: @Raphael Every element you extract results in at most $3$ new elements getting created, so you generate at most $3N$ nodes. The graph is really just an analogy to show the similarity with Dijkstra's algorithm, all you are really doing is pushing 1 on to a priority queue, and then repeatedly extracting the minimum from the priority queue (let this number be $x$) and pushing $3x,5x$ and $7x$ back on to the queue.