# Finding all "smooth" numbers up to 10^6 -- problem with nested loops

Tags: algorithms, number-theory

A [smooth number] is one whose factors are all "small".  For a computational problem, I would like all smooth numbers up to $10^8$.

I think it's unfeasible to factor a billion numbers.  Instead, I am choosing a set of primes, $P = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31\}$.  How can I find all possible product of them less than a billion?

$$\left\{ (k_2, \dots, k_{31}) :  N = \prod_{p \in P} p^{k_p} < 10^9 \right\}$$

The solution is not too hard since $\log_2 10^9 = 9 \log_2 10 < 9\cdot 4 = 36 $ I never have to go too high.

---

My original question: I really need to index over all possible product, but **how do I avoid writing 13 nested loops**?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I generate first n elements of the sequence 3^i \* 5^j \* 7^k?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39689/how-can-i-generate-first-n-elements-of-the-sequence-3i-5j-7k). This is the same question, only with more factors to take into consideration. The answers to the $3^i5^j7$ problem generalize just fine to 13 possible factors.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Notice in the question $i,j,k \geq 1$ but in the answer $i,j,k \geq 0$, but yeah.

Comment: I agree with @DavidRicherby. When implementing the answers, though, be mindful of memory and/or recursion depth. Generating the first $N$ elements you kind of know what you do, but generating all elements up to some value you might be getting more than you asked for.

Comment: @johnmangual It's common to include zero in the natural numbers so the question can be read as $i,j,k\geq 0$. In any case, you want to allow $i,j,k,\ell,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u\geq 0$. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am in agreement, this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find it the way it was phrased.  Thanks!

Comment: @johnmangual I'm sure I woudln't have found the other question by searching, either. I only remembered it because it was posted a few days ago.