# Hamming numbers for $O(N)$ speed and $O(1)$ memory

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

Disclaimer: there are many questions about it, but I didn't find any with requirement of constant memory.

Hamming numbers is a numbers $2^i 3^j 5^k$, where $i$, $j$, $k$ are natural numbers.

Is there a possibility to generate Nth Hamming number with $O(N)$ time and $O(1)$ (constant) memory? Under generate I mean exactly the generator, i.e. you can only output the result and not read the previously generated numbers (in that case memory will be not constant). But you can save some constant number of them.

I see only best algorithm with constant memory is not better than $O(N log N)$, for example, based on priority queue.

But is there mathematical proof that it is impossible to construct an algorithm in $O(N)$ time and $O(1)$ memory?

Comment: Why do you consider a priority queue to be of constant memory?

Comment: @HendrikJan We can use ln(2), ln(3) and ln(5) for calculating each number, but not in correct sequence. And we can put them in priority queue for autosorting.

Comment: But storing that sequence to be sorted is not constant memory?

Comment: @HendrikJan I think (but not sure) that we can limit size of the priority queue to some big but constant value (less than N, of course)

Comment: Would be interesting.  I have given a solution without PQ http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39689/how-can-i-generate-first-n-elements-of-the-sequence-3i-5j-7k/39708#39708 using three pointers to a list. The PQ is avoided since we only need to take the minimum of three values. Your idea seems to suggest that only a bounded sequence of numbers needs to be stored in that list.

Comment: "O(N) time and O(1) (constant) memory" with how many heads on the input tape? ​ (If just 1, then "O(N) time" would follow automatically from "O(1) (constant) memory".) ​ ​ ​ ​